# Use of the GLOBALS paramater

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to do this?
NOTE: I'm new to PHP

```
<?php     
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT naam FROM lowavolPloegen WHERE ploeg_id='4' ORDER BY voornaam, naam");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $ploegNaam = $row['naam'];
            echo $ploegNaam;
        }
?>
```

Here comes some html text

```
<?php
    echo GLOBALS['$ploegNaam'];
?>
```

Comment: is it the same page ?

Comment: yes it's on the same page

Comment: This should help you: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Comment: why you use globals ? just  `echo$ploegNaam` , and also , when you use global , you don't add $ to key , it should be  echo `GLOBALS['ploegNaam'];`

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
echo $GLOBALS['ploegNaam'];
```

You need `$` before the name of the `GLOBALS` array to indicate that it's a variable name, and the key is just the name of the global variable without the `$`.